# data-parent Bootstrap

Tags: front-end, bootstrap, collapse

Estou tendo dificuldades com o data-parent para collapsar no bootstrap

```
<div class="panel-group" id="paineis-sobre">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item1">
            <h3 class="panel-title" data-parent="#paineis-sobre">Desde 2014</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body collapse in" id="item1">
            <p>Standing in the line to see the show tonight and there's a light on, heavy glow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item2">
            <h3 class="panel-title" data-parent="#paineis-sobre">Desde 2014</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body collapse" id="item2">
            <p>Standing in the line to see the show tonight and there's a light on, heavy glow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item3">
            <h3 class="panel-title" data-parent="#paineis-sobre">Desde 2014</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body collapse" id="item3">
            <p>Standing in the line to see the show tonight and there's a light on, heavy glow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As divs não collapsam ao clicar em outra do mesmo grupo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o atributo data-parent funcione, deve-se colocar o mesmo na div que contém o título, paragrafo, ou qualquer outro elemento que queira utilizar